# List out of index error Python

Tags: python, list

I seem to be getting a strange list index out of range error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./test.py", line 7, in <module>
print  column[2]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

For this simple line of code,

```
DIR = 'path/to/test.vcf'

for line in open(DIR):
        column = line.split()
        print  column[2]
```

Where column outputs:

```
['chr1', '19964150', '.', 'AAAAGAAAAAGAAAAAGAA', '.', '0', '.','END=19964169;MOTIF=AAAAAG;REF=3.16667;RL=19;RPA=.;RU=AAAAGA;VT=STR', 'GT:ALLREADS:AML:DP:GB:PL:Q:STITCH', '0/0:0|6:1/1:6:0/0:0:1:1']
```

column[0] outputs:

```
chr1
```

But any other integer index and it gives me an error
Why would I be receiving this error if column is a list with 10[9 by list logic] split strings?

Comment: *"Why would I be receiving this error if column is a list with 10 split strings?"* - you wouldn't, so that assumption can't be true! Do you have blank lines in your file?

Comment: Hate to break it to you, but `column` isn't always ten fields.  Ask your data.

Comment: I used .split to remove whitespace, and create a list with only the information I need, but i cannot access it if it keeps throwing me an index out of range error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be line(s) that does not match your expectation. (line with less columns / blank line).

Guard the line that access the third column to avoid the exception.

```
DIR = 'path/to/test.vcf'

for line in open(DIR):
    column = line.split()
    if len(column) > 2:
        print column[2]
```

Comment: Ahh you are right there were 12 lines at the beginning of the file that  were commented out, and it was listing those separate